# AngularJS and gulp - getting less errors than I think I should in the console

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm building a site. First I made myself familiar with AngularJS in general and tried to make sense of all the new things for me: grunt, livereload, angularjs... I soon realized some mistakes I made and started building a new project from the ground up.

When I was building the site whilst on the grunt server. It displayed me more messages than it is now with gulp. I'm not sure why is that?

For example, since I was moving some existing code from my "study-project" to a new clean-start-gulp-project. I forgot to add one service: FlashService - responsible for displaying simple messages on my site.

And I was already using that as a dependency in another service. But for some reason all I was presented was a blank site with no messages in the console. Whereas in my previous project I always got messages like "No such provider found" or something similar. Can anybody help me make debuging easier?

Some other things have changed also. I changed the general folder structure of the code and I'm trying to modularize my new app. Currently I can't think of anything else that might even be remotely related.

My current folder structure is like this:

```
src/app
    app.js
    /services
        auth-service.js
        flash-service.js
```

Some important parts from my code:

**app.js**

```
angular.module('myapp', [

   ...
   'myapp.home'

]).config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('main', {
        'abstract': true,
        resolve: {
            promiseUser: ['AuthService', function (AuthService) { AuthService.promiseUser; }]
        },
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    });
})
```

**AuthService**

```
angular.module('myapp').service('AuthService', ['FlashService', function (FlashService){

    // As soon as I created the missing service 'FlashService' everything started working. 
    // Or when I simply removed the FlashService from dependencies. 
    // What I don't understand is why didn't I get any errors in the console?

}
```

Since I already spent too much time looking the bug in a wrong place I can only imagine that some other messages might also not make it into the console. This would eventually make debuging quite hard.

What am I missing here? Why didn't I get any errors in the console?

**Edit:**
The first project was generated using Yeoman and for the second one I used gulp slush. Don't think this will help, but I figured might be worth mentioning.

**Edit2**
Found out that if I change angular.js and add console.log(message) inside the first minError function, I almost get what I want.

```
function minErr(module) {
    ...
    console.log(message);
    return new Error(message);
}
```

Now I just need to figure out an alternative way to do this or what was different with yeoman generated application and why I am not getting these messages by default:

```
[$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: aProvider <- a <- AuthService
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.25/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20AuthService
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I'll try to explain what I figured out.

This had nothing to do with gulp nor grunt. Also the directory structure was completely irrelevant.

First, let's take a look at some of the most important parts of both config files.

**current:**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])

.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('main', {
        'abstract': true,
        resolve: {
            promiseUser: ['AuthService', function (AuthService) { AuthService.promiseUser; }]
        },
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    });
})

...
```

**before:**

```
angular.module('myapp', [])

.config(function ($stateProvider) {

    $stateProvider.state('main', {
        'abstract': true,
        resolve: {
            promiseUser: ['AuthService', function (AuthService) { AuthService.promiseUser; }]
        },
        template: '<div ui-view></div>'
    });
})

...

.run(['AuthService', function (AuthService) { ... }]);

...
```

So the first part is the same in both cases. What was different before is that I also used AuthService inside a run block. 
I was checking that on state change the authenticated user had permissions to access the new state.

So what happened inside the resolve stayed inside the resolve! But what happened inside the run block was displayed in the console.

By modifying these parts of the code - both projects displayed the same errors and had the same behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Loading modules with Angular if you want error messages always try and catch.  My guess that gulp slush is not generating a try/catch scenario for loading modules while yeoman does.  The difference between gulp and grunt shouldn't matter so long as you are trying to catch the error.  The thing with gulp is that it is all process based some of something failed in the process sometimes the process will just sit there or just stop all together.

Disclaimer: I have never generated a project with slush only yeoman.

Comment: Actually I have found out that the reason why I didn't get the error was because AuthService was used inside a resolve. Whereas the previous project used it in resolve and also to set up the main module... `.config(...['AuthService', function(AuthService){...}])`. And that is why I got the error right away before. Later, when I decided to go on with writing code the errors were as expected. When I get a little bit more information, I will also post the answer here. It came out when I tested some more similar cases in my previous project.

Comment: Ahh I am not sure why module setup would happen inside a resolve but everyone has their reasons.

Comment: I think I wasn't clear. So I have the same resolve in both applications, but my previous main module had some extra stuff going on which I hadn't implemented yet in the new app. One part of it started like this:
`.run(function ($rootScope, $state, AuthService, FlashService) {...})`. And this made the difference. It was already trying to use AuthService and found out that AuthService has one serviceProvider which doesn't exist. But when I only used AuthService inside a resolve, I just got a whitepage - maybe has something to do with ui-router?

Comment: Still seems like I can't fully explain it. I'll try to formulate an answer in a few days.